# I used webhook to call the skill in amazon alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

When user call any intent it is replies with appropriate answer, Now when alexa replies with the answer user says STOP, Getting There was a problem with the requested skill's response.

How to use the Build-in-intents in webhook.

Comment: When you post a question at least include something to look upon, like the response JSON

Comment: https://api.myjson.com/bins/j4ubs this is the input json in output i am getting NULL

Comment: Check what is your backend returning for a STOP intent from backend logs

Comment: Can we use Build-in-intents without calling the Backend service.

Comment: No you can’t. You will always have to handle every request.

Comment: Thanks For sharing Thomas.Ill try to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"There was a problem with the requested skill's response."** generally means that there is something wrong with your response. When the users say "Stop", `AMAZON.StopIntent` will be triggered. Make sure that your `AMAZON.StopIntent` handler respond back with a correct response JSON.

A sample response for `AMAZON.StopIntent` will look like this:

```
{
    "body": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "response": {
            "outputSpeech": {
                "type": "SSML",
                "ssml": "<speak> Bye </speak>"
            },
            "shouldEndSession": true
        },
        "sessionAttributes": {}
    }
}
```